# How to distinguish between Enter and Escape key presses in interactive Windows bat/cmd scripts (cmd.exe)?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, interactive

The Pause command exits on Enter and Escape keys, but does not return a distinctive ErrorLevel.
The Choice command does not return when pressing any of the Enter or Escape keys.

Comment: If it's even possible, it's going to be ugly trying to do this with a pure batch file. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Enter should repeat the (failed) action, Escape should quit the bat file. In my particular case, I want to close the window on Escape and to Re-Open a SQL script on Enter after Oracle SqlPlus has crashed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this question interesting and wanted to add one other possible solution, powershell `ReadKey`

**Command**

```
PowerShell Exit($host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey('NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown').VirtualKeyCode);
```

**Usage**

```
@echo off
set /p "=> Single Key Prompt? " <nul
PowerShell Exit($host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey('NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown').VirtualKeyCode);
echo KeyCode = %ErrorLevel%
```

**Output: Enter Key**

```
> Single Key Prompt? 
KeyCode = 13
```

**Output: Escape Key**

```
> Single Key Prompt? KeyCode = 27
```

**References**

[TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730938.aspx)

[PS Pause Alternative](http://adamstech.wordpress.com/2011/05/12/how-to-properly-pause-a-powershell-script/)

Comment: This one, as opposed to the xcopy solution, really does what I asked for: Besides the Enter, it detects even a single ESC keypress.

Answer (score 3):

For detecting ENTER you can use XCOPY, really...
But detecting a single ESC seems not possible with pure batch.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

call :GetKey
if "!key!"=="" echo ENTER
if "!key!"==" " echo SPACE
exit /b

:GetKey
set "key="
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%L in (`xcopy /L /w "%~f0" "%~f0" 2^>NUL`) do (
  if not defined key set "key=%%L"
)
set "key=%key:~-1%"
exit /b
```

This works, as `xcopy /L /W` asks for a keypress to start copying and then it shows the key and ends.

Comment: Great ! This fancy thing really works with windows standard software (no additional installs) when I'm using Enter instead of Escape. In fact, it also works without delayed expansion (using "%key%" instead of "!key!"). Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this using choose32.exe (http://www.westmesatech.com/editv.html):

```
choose32 -c ^A^[ -d ^A -q -n -p "ESC to quit, ENTER to continue: "
```

^A is Ctrl+A (ASCII character 1), and ^[ is Ctrl+[ (ASCII character 27, or Esc). Command line breakdown:

- -c specifies what keystrokes are valid (in this case, Ctrl+A and Esc).
- -d tells which choice to use if Enter pressed (a "default" choice).
- -n hides the list of choices.
- -q does not display the keystroke that was pressed.
- -p Specifies the prompt to display.

In this case, choose32 returns exit code of 2 if Esc pressed, or exit code of 1 if Enter pressed.

Comment: Thank you, but there is no choose32 on my Win7. And I'm not allowed to install it on my work PC.

Comment: Choose32.exe is a stand-alone .exe file that requires no installation.

Comment: Re-checked it with no success: dir /s c:\choose32* does not return any result on my Win 7 Professional SP1 64-bit. And I'm not allowed to use any non-approved (foreign) software on my work PC.

Comment: You would have to download choose32.exe and put it in a directory in your path. If you are not allowed to use downloaded software, then obviously this is not a workable solution for you unless you get it approved.